# Sencha Touch 2 complex list layout: Container, TabPanel, lists and panels

Tags: list, extjs, layout, scroll, sencha-touch

I want to achieve the following layout for my ST 2.3 app:

- Navigation view

  - Container

    - TabPanel

      - List
    - Panel
    - Panel

I want the list scroll disabled to scroll with the content of the container (along with the tabpanel et panels). The list and the panels height are flexible and I can't know them because it depends on the size of images, dynamically loaded, and the size of the device's screen.

I tried several different layouts (fit, vbox, default) but nothing works, the closest I got was to define the height of the tabpanel by counting the records of the list, but as the height of the records depends of the images which are not loaded when the list is rendered I can't get the actual height of each raw...

Any idea how to achieve this? I can provide some code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lists must have their own scroller in sencha touch. Try a dataview instead with a vbox layout on the container. Make sure all sub-items to the scrollable container have scrollable:null on them so they don't default to a height of 0.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The vbox layout forces the components to all fit on the screen, no ?

Comment: No, that's not correct. Vbox aligns them all vertically. If you set any to have a flex, that will try to fill to take up the space left by the others, so you wouldn't use that for instance if you wanted a scroller on the component.